# How can I "pin" one node to left viewport edge, while keeping other node horizontally centered relative to viewport?

Tags: css, flexbox

How can I pin `Menu` to the left edge of the viewport, while keeping `My Awesome Site` horizontally centered (relative to the viewport)? `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center` are just starting points... I don't know if I need to use a combination of other Flexbox rules.

Requirements:

- Use Flexbox.
- Don't add any more HTML.
- Keep the CSS as clean as possible.

Notes:

- `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center` are just guesses... I'm cool with other Flexbox combinations.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
a {
  background-color: beige;
}
h1 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a>Menu</a>
  <h1>My Awesome Site</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: Why is using flexbox a *requirement*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple and efficient that comes to mind is using `position: absolute`, though based on other requirements it might need another solution

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-color: beige;
}
h1 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a>Menu</a>
  <h1>My Awesome Site</h1>
</header>
```

If you can give the "Menu" a fixed width, you can do this,

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
a {
  width: 80px;  
  margin-right: -80px;
  background-color: beige;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a>Menu</a>
  <h1>My Awesome Site</h1>
</header>
```

or this.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
a {
  width: 80px;  
  background-color: beige;
}
h1 {
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 80px;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a>Menu</a>
  <h1>My Awesome Site</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: The first fixed-width solution is good enough for me. Although, I'd prefer adding `h1 { padding-right: <width of a> }` instead of `a { margin-right: <negative width of a> }` so that the two elements' boxes don't overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `margin-left` and `right` to `auto`, you can align the second element in the center.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
a {
  background-color: beige;
}
h1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a>Menu</a>
  <h1>My Awesome Site</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: This will not center the `h1` relative to viewport

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. I haven't added more HTML but I just used the semantic naming.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB">
    <head>
        <title>My Awesome Site</title>
        <style>
            html, body {
                padding: 0; margin: 0;
            }

            .my-awesome-flex-container {
                display: flex;
            }

            .my-awesome-flex-item {
                padding: 1em;
                flex-grow: 1;
            }

            .my-awesome-menu {
                background-color: #3d94a6;
            }

            .my-awesome-site {
                background-color: #c8c8c3;
                text-align: center;
                flex-grow: 6;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="my-awesome-flex-container">
            <nav class="my-awesome-flex-item my-awesome-menu">
                Menu
            </nav>

            <section class="my-awesome-flex-item my-awesome-site">
                My Awesome Site
            </section>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You changed the elements that are being used, which is basically the same thing as adding new ones...

Comment: @TylerH I think you are right because each tag is rendered differently. Im modifying my answer.

Comment: This will not center the `section` relative to viewport